# Conditions for the existence of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} (f(x)g(x))$ exist, must $\lim_{x \to b} g(x)$ exist?

Let $f,g$ be two functions defined in some open interval $I$ containing a point $a$. Let us suppose that $a=b$.
Let $\epsilon>0$. We know that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)g(x))$ exist.
Therefore, let $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=l$ and $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)g(x))=l'$.
Since $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=l$ and $\lim_{x \to a}(f(x)g(x))=l'$, there exists $\eta_1>0$ and $\eta_2>0$ such that:

$\forall x \in I $ 
\begin{array}{lcl} 
\mid x-a \mid \leq \eta_1 \Rightarrow \mid f(x)-l \mid \leq \\ 
\mid x-a \mid \leq \eta_2 \Rightarrow \mid f(x)g(x)-l' \mid \leq \epsilon\\
\end{array}

I didn't find the first line has to be smaller that and how to I reveal the $g(x)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What could go wrong if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x \to b} g(x)$ not necessarily exist. If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=0$, for example, $f(x)=\sin{x}$,  $a=0$, $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: So I can simply state that as a counter example ?

Comment: In your counter example do I consider as well a=b?

Comment: In case $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=0$ — yes.

Comment: Ok. I understood. Thank you

Comment: Generally, limit behaviour of $g$ at point $b \ne a$  not must depend from its values at $a$.

Comment: So the counter example is sufficient since we've found a situation where the limit of g does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$
\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}
$$

and applying the theorem on the limit of the ratio, if the two limits are finite and the limit of $f$ is not $0$, this becomes

$$
\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}
$$

so in these hypotheses it exists.
This does not exclude that the limit could exist also if the hypotheses are not satisfied.

Comment: Yes but that is useful for later in the proof.

What element which is strictly positive should I chose such that I will have: $\mid f(x)-l \mid \leq$ "that element"

Comment: @user43418: I do not want to do a proof if I can use an already known theorem.